# I replaced a url with an image to create a magnifying glass - now not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

I found a tutorial on how to create a cool magnifying glass by hovering over an image at the link below.  I want to substitute the url he provides for the image in the demo with my own jpg.  I created the files and got the effect to work.  I then downloaded his iphone image at the url he provides and substituted the url with the saved jpg.  The image appears as does the magnifying glass hovering over it but now the enlarged image does not appear.  Since I want to ultimately use my own jpg, I need to understand why the enlarged image does not work when swapping out the url.  I assume it has something to do with the js but am not sure.  Thanks if anyone can help.

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Comment: you need a large image both on the page and in the css

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to answer your question thoroughly. From looking at the code on the website though, I would assume that you've missed either missed changing one of the urls (there's one in the html and another in the css) or have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I did change both the css and the html.  I wish I could post my code but I can't figure out how to do that.  When I type on the html and code buttons above my post, boxes with text that is not editable appear.  I also cannot find "how to" guides at the home page that might guide me.  Frustrating.

Comment: Check out this link for advice on editing your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Replace both the image in the css and on the html

```
<img class="small" src="newimage.jpg" width="100"/>

.large {
    background: url('newimage.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8vx8dqs/1/